# Проблемы с восстановлением сайта на Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, xampp

Всем привет.
Есть бэкап Joomla сайта, сделанный в Akeeba. Сайт нужно восстановить на другой локальной машине.
При попытке восстановить сайт выдается следующая ошибка.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что с ней можно сделать?

Несколько дополнительных вводных:

- установлен xampp с php 7.013, Сайт создавался на Joomla c php 5.5.9. Может быть в этом проблема?
- У меня очень мало опыта в работе с Joomla.
- Пытался создать свою базу данных(пустую) через встроенный phpmyadmin и ввести ее название (скорее всего, глупое действие), ничего не вышло.

Заранее благодарю всех откликнувшихся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведённой ошибке ясно написано "Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL", просто надо в configuraton.php сменить на новые доступы к базе

```
public $user = 'DB user';
public $password = 'User password';
public $db = 'database name';
```

Если востановление делается через стороннею программу, то надо в настройка найти доступы для подключения к базе.

Comment: Делаю попытку воспользоваться Вашим советом:

Comment: Делаю попытку воспользоваться Вашим советом: В указанном файле задал данные в эти переменные. в переменную db занес название вновь созданной пустой базы данных. Проблема не решена. Я делаю что-то не то?  Касательно сторонней программы - бэкап сделан посредством Akeeba, распаковка производилась им же. Куда в итоге нужно прописать доступ к базе? Или Akeeba не имеет уже к этом отношения?

Comment: Насколько я понял, установку делаете на localhost ?
что вы вписали в настройках $user и $password ?

Comment: Все верно. Туда вписал данные пользователя, которому дал доступ к базе данных. То есть, через phpmyadmin в базе данных добавил пользвателя с парой логин/пароль - joomla/joomla со всеми правами доступа, в переменные файла вписал то же самое.

Comment: Еще раз все вбил и в итоге получилось, благодаря Вам.

Comment: Вот и хорошо! ))